# In Scala is it possible to reference the object being copied in the copy statement

Tags: scala

Is there a way to reference the object being copied in a copy statement without having to assign the object to a variable?

For instance I can do this:

```
case class Foo(s: String)
val f = Foo("a")
f.copy(s = f.s + "b")
```

But I want to do this:

```
case class Foo(s: String)
Foo("a").copy(s = this.s + "b")
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 7):

Not directly.  People sometimes define a pipe method to deal with this sort of thing (not just for case classes).  In 2.10:

```
implicit class PipeEverything[A](val value: A) extends AnyVal {
  def |>[Z](f: A => Z) = f(value)
}
```

but this doesn't always save that much space:

```
Foo("a") |> (x => x.copy(s = x.s + "b"))
{ val x = Foo("a"); x.copy(s = x.s + "b") }
```

Keep in mind that you can put a code block practically anywhere in Scala, so just creating a transient val is not usually a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer to your question, but an aside.

You might want to look into [lenses](https://blog.stackmob.com/2012/02/an-introduction-to-lenses-in-scalaz/), which will allow you to do something like:

```
case class Foo(s: String)
sLens.mod(Foo("a"), _ + "b")
```

You can define `sLens` yourself or have it [auto-generated using a compiler plugin](https://github.com/gseitz/Lensed).